# WriteAsync() and WriteLineAsync() c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method that need to write the results in a text file. I use Async/Await in c# 5 to write text file asynch, but I think the program run sync. does it have any impact on performance? What is the correct format for WriteLineAsync()?

```
public static void Do()
{
    for(int i=1;i<1000;i++)
    {
         //Here I want to do something
         Write1();
         Write2();
    }
}  


private static async void Write1()
{
    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\R.txt"))
    {
        await str.WriteLineAsync(string.Format("{0}",Public.FullTime.Elapsed));
    }
}

private static async void write2()
{
    using (StreamWriter PStr = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\p.txt"))
    {
        await PStr.WriteAsync(StrBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The write is not synchronous, but you're waiting for it to finish, so you actually gain nothing from the asynchrony.

If you don't want to wait for the end of the call, you can create a new `Task` and start it. This will perform the writing on a different thread.

Comment: You **do** potentially gain something because although you are _waiting_, you are not _blocking_. If you've got many of these methods being called concurrently it will make a huge difference, and if you're doing this in a UI thread, it will prevent any chance of a blocking call freezing up your UI when you fill the stream's buffer.

Comment: I noticed I need to use Task.Wait(), Otherwise I would miss some data. Please give me a solution because I think there is no difference and I need to wait until stream writer do their job. what is the usage of async/await!

Comment: Are you missing data because your process exits?

Comment: I call the methods in a loop then in each loop the methods are called. At the beginning, data missed but after some loops I think everything works well. But I missed part of my first data.